# How does python remember values of enclosing scope's variable when nested function in called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I read an example on closure

```
def outer():
        x = 1
        def inner():
           print x # 1
        return inner
```

The life of our variable x is only till the time the function outer runs .
When i call outer and it returns the adress of inner , the variable x should have died because the function outer has exited but still how can i acess it through the returned inner function ?

[python variable scope in nested functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228396/python-variable-scope-in-nested-functions)

This link answered that the value of variables used by inner is stored when outer returns inner function to caller , but

Now see this code

```
 def outer():
            x = 1
            def inner():
               print x*n # n not defined anywhere
            return inner
```

I ran this code and
This piece of code doesn't give any error when i call outer , that means that python doesn't checks the variables used by inner function while running outer . so how does it know it has to retain 'x' , after exiting ?

Comment: `so how does it know it has to retain 'x' , after exiting` - because it is used by `inner`?

Comment: You should look up `super`. Also, I like how you said, "Now see this code," Like look at this code. Just look at it.

Answer (score 3):

> The life of our variable x is only till the time the function outer runs

No. `x` lives as long as it's reachable from somewhere. And, it is — from the `inner` function.

> This piece of code doesn't give any error when i call outer , that means that python doesn't checks the variables used by inner function while running outer

`n` could be defined **after** calling `outer`, but **before** calling its result, `inner`. In that case `inner`'s body if perfectly legitimate.

If you didn't return `inner`, then there'd be no reason to keep `x`, because you can't reach `inner`, thus can't somehow involve `x` into computation.

Comment: So does this mean that python checks the code inside def and keeps record of all variables used to keep them in some namespace ?

Comment: @ShikharSrivastava, No. It keeps all variables by default, but sometimes check if some variables become unreachable and can be safely deallocated. See [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science))

Comment: I mean to say that when the outer function exits , all its local variables should die (they are not used anywhere else) but x doesn't die and can be accessed by inner , then does it mean python attaches reference to the global , enclosed scope's namespaces with inner function object ?

Comment: @ShikharSrivastava, they don't die at the moment of exit. They die when the garbage collection is called and have found out that these variables are not reachable anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The way `x` is remembered is because python has a special `__closure__` attribute that remembers the object from the enclosing scope that the local function needs and keeps a `reference` to it so it can be used in the local function:

```
def outer():
    x = 1
    def inner():
        print(x)
    return inner

o = outer()

print(o.__closure__)
(<cell at 0x7fa18a2fc588: int object at 0x9f8800>,)
```

If you assign `o = outer()` and then call `o()` you are then calling the `inner` function and you will get an error, calling `outer()`  does not call the inner function.

If you were to declare a function `f` and put a `print(n)` in the body then unless you actually call `f` you won't get an error so the same logic applies to your inner function, you are not actually calling it  with `outer()` so you don't get an error:

```
def f():
    print(n) # will only error when we actually call `f()`
```

If calling the `inner` function happened when you called  `outer` it would defeat the purpose, consider the following function factory where we take in an exponent `e` to raise `i` to:

```
def raise_exp(e):
    def power(i):
        return  i ** e # n not defined anywhere
    return power

sq = raise_exp(2) # set exponent but does not call power 
print(sq(2)) # now we actually all power
cube = raise_exp(3)
print(cube(3))

25
27
```

Comment: @ShikharSrivastava, no worries, it does seem a little confusing at first but once you understand what is going on it is easy to follow.